# javascript string shows up in alert box but not in array push

Tags: javascript, html

This is really weird and hours of googling didn't find an answer.  I'm trying to read a local file using javascript. I just output some properties of the text file, including the first line, to see if it is reading it ok.  It seems to be working except for one thing.  When I click the Browse button, select a file, and click Ok, the javascript string assigned to firstLine correctly shows up in the alert box but not in output.push. Here is the main code:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; // FileList object

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(f);
    reader.onload = function(e) { 
        var contents = e.target.result;
        var firstLine = contents.substr(0, contents.indexOf("\n"));
        alert( "Got the file\n" 
              +"name: " + f.name + "\n"
              +"type: " + f.type + "\n"
              +"size: " + f.size + " bytes\n"
              +"starts with: " + firstLine       //firstLine correctly shows up here
        );      
        var output = [];
        output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                  ' starts with: '+ firstLine,    //but not here
                  '</li>');
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
    };
  }
  document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

I have the following two lines just above the script tag within the head section:

```
<input type="file" id="files" />
<output id="list"></output>
```

Another weird thing is if I put these two lines in the body section where I really want them, the input element shows up but nothing shows up for the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works just fine. Note that I moved the last line of your javascript into a function that's called after the page has finished loading. I get the file's text displayed both in the alert box and on the page itself. (Google Chrome Version 32.0.1700.76 m)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function byId(e){return document.getElementById(e);}

window.addEventListener('load', mInit, false);

function mInit()
{
  byId('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
}

function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var f = evt.target.files[0]; // FileList object

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(f);
    reader.onload = function(e) { 
        var contents = e.target.result;
        var firstLine = contents.substr(0, contents.indexOf("\n"));
        alert( "Got the file\n" 
              +"name: " + f.name + "\n"
              +"type: " + f.type + "\n"
              +"size: " + f.size + " bytes\n"
              +"starts with: " + firstLine       //firstLine correctly shows up here
        );      
        var output = [];
        output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
                  f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
                  f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
                  ' starts with: '+ firstLine,    //but not here
                  '</li>');
        document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
    };
  }
</script>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="file" id="files" />
    <output id="list"></output> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but am still getting the same result.  I also tried it in chrome (Version 32.0.1700.76 m) but got the same result there too.  Since yours worked, it makes me wonder if it has something to do with the size of the file being read. Mine is 400K.  I just created a 2 liner test text file and indeed, that worked.  Not sure how to make it work for a 400K file.

Comment: Now that does seem strange to me. I just tried it with a 1600x1000px PNG file. The file is 955kb, and while the content is binary and clearly wont print very well (since there's a null character in the header that terminates output) - it does produce the following output on the page (as well as some output in the message-box) `bamboo.png (image/png) - 978701 bytes, last modified: 23/12/2013 starts with: �PNG` Very strange indeed, bookmarked.

Comment: Hmm, it must not be file size then.  Here is the output that works: test.txt (text/plain) - 25 bytes, last modified: Tuesday, January 21, 2014 starts with: this is a test  ...  and here is the one that doesn't: greg_hanowski_ccda.xml (text/xml) - 396277 bytes, last modified: Saturday, January 18, 2014 starts with:    ... agree, really strange

Comment: Here is the actual first line of the xml file: <?xml version="1.0"?>  which correctly shows up in the alert box

Comment: Apparently the browser is interpreting that line, rather than printing it out literally.  If I use escape(firstLine), then it outputs: greg_hanowski_ccda.xml (text/xml) - 396277 bytes, last modified: Saturday, January 18, 2014 starts with: %3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%3F%3E

Comment: Ahhh! You beat me by 44 seconds! I was just going to say that the xml file's tags will be interpreted and not printed literally on the page.